# Was Grigory Rasputin a mutant?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant

We know that a couple of Marvel mutants descended from [Grigory Rasputin](https://marvel.wikia.com/Grigory_Efimovich_Rasputin_%28Earth-616%29) (e.g. Colossus [Pyotr] and his brother Michael and IIRC their cousins).

Yet, none of the Wiki/Wikia pages actually mention of Rasputin himself was a mutant, other metahuman, or just happened to be a human Bad Guy who worked with mutants (Mr. Sinister). What was he?

Comment: That would explain why his penis has its own *Wikipedia* entry.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, Grigory Efimovich Rasputin of the Earth-616 continuity was indeed a mutant.

- He was also the progenitor to a line of mutants including Peter Rasputin (Colossus), Mikhail Rasputin, and Illyana Rasputina (Magick). His only appearance in the Marvel Universe is in *X-Men: Colossus Bloodline* Vol 1 Issues 1-5 (2005).
- He discovered his mutation through his interactions with the scientist Nathaniel Essex who has been transformed by Apocalypse into Mr. Sinister. Sinister was investigating people with the "Essex Factor" (genetic markers Sinister believed indicated an individual could have mutant propensities).
- Sinister's search lead him to Czarist Russia and his discovery Grigory Rasputin. After studying Rasputin and determining he indeed had the "Essex Factor" the two of them concocted a plan to have Rasputin share his DNA with as many women as possible in order to see if it would be possible to breed a fully active mutant. Only one of the women, Elena would lead to the successful line Essex sought producing Colossus, Illyana and Mikhail.
- Elena's brother would lead the Czar to try and kill Rasputin, first by poison (which by the way had no effect) and then later by shooting him in the head. Rasputin survived long enough to gather his brides together and share his psychic essence with them before he died.

**Grigory Efimovich Rasputin's mutant abilities were subtle and quite unusual.**

- He was physically robust and had no problem grappling potential assassins killing them with his madness-induced strength. He appeared to have no difficulty fighting more than one opponent at a time.
- When the Prince tried to poison him, he appeared immune to the cyanide poison placed in his wine. Rasputin was also quite physically resilient. He boasted of several stabbings and other injuries that given the state of medicine in the 1850s should have lead to his death. He claimed he was saved by God for a higher purpose.
- He had a fantastic charisma, using his eyes and voice to sway people to do almost anything he wanted. It appeared to work as a form of hypnotic suggestion and women were especially susceptible. It was said he even worked his physical charms on royalty on occasion.
- His more notable mutation allowed him to disperse his consciousness into his descendants and hide in their minds, as a voice that would eventually drive many of the family members to madness and eventual suicide. In one feeble-minded member of his family line, he was able to assume control of the body and the mind and was able to remember more of his past as Grigory Rasputin. His willpower appeared to be superhuman allowing him to be able divide and reconstitute himself centuries after his death.
- His psychic immortality came at a high price. While it would allow him to retain knowledge of himself and his past, it required him to kill his descendants allowing his mind fragments to return to wherever his mind and will were strongest.

In the *Colossus* storyline, Mr. Sinister and Grigory concoct a plan to kill all of Rasputin's descendants in order to restore Grigory to life in the last living body that remain of his bloodline. He would use his superior will to take over the body, destroying the former owner's mind in the process. These panels are from *X-Men: Colossus Bloodline* Vol 1 Issue 4.

[image: Rasputin explaining what the "bloodline" is]